# ReactJS: Getting 404 when a /about page is opened

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, firebase-hosting

This is the first time I'm deploying a React Web App to the firebase hosting. In my `index.html` file I only have the root div:

```
<body>
    <div id="root" class="container"></div>
</body>
```

That's all there is in the body. Then I have an `index.js` in the `src` folder in which I have:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";'
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";
import AboutScreen from "./screens/AboutScreen";
...
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={HomeScreen} />
            <Route exact path="/about" component={AboutScreen} />
        </div>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById("root"))
```

Then to open the about page I have linked it as:

```
import { Container, Nav, Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap';
...
<Nav.Link href="/about">About</Nav.Link>
```

When I do `npm run build` and then `firebase deploy` it deploys and I can see the changes on the home page. But when I click on `about` it gives me `404`

[image: 404 error picture]

I have the folder named `build` which is the public folder and after the build, it only has `index.html` and `404.html` and a `static/js` folder that has some generated `js` and `txt`.

So, I'm not sure why I'm getting 404. In dev build i.e. `localhost` the navigation works fine.

Comment: can you show your `.htaccess` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because it is a static deployment of a single `index.html`, `about.html` does not exist, you can only access to the index.html, and the other views "doesn't" because is a single-page-application, but you can redirect all URL other than "/" to the `index.html` file, editing the firebase.json

```
"rewrites": [ {
  "source": "**",
  "destination": "/index.html"
} ]
```

Comment: I'm not sure why I made it a single-page application. If I do `firebase init` in the project folder and select `N` to single page application will it work or do I still need to change the `firebase.json`?

Answer (score 0):

For single page applications, redirect rules must be specified.
Every routes should be redirected from `index.html` file

You need to specify the deployment directory being deployed and the redirect rules

This is my react app being deployed to firebase hosting alongside firebase functions

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  }
}
```